# Rails params not completely received by using cURL command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl

I am pretty new to Rails, I've met a weird issue when I was writing Rails API.

My **Controller** looks like this:

```
class Api::PipelineController < ApplicationController
   before_action :query_params

  def index
    job_id  = params[:job_id].to_i
    build_num = params[:build_num].to_i
    ...
    @result= {"foo"=>"bar"}
    ...

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @result }
    end
  end

  private
  def query_params
    params.except('controller', 'format', 'action').permit(:job_id, :build_num)
  end
 end
```

And my request API looks like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3456/api/pipeline?job_id=16&build_num=23
```

The weird thing is when I request this API from a GUI tool like POSTMAN, It works normal and the backend rails log looks like this:

```
Started GET "/api/pipeline?job_id=16&build_num=23" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-15 23:07:27 +0800
Processing by Api::PipelineController#index as JSON
Parameters: {"job_id"=>"16", "build_num"=>"23"}
```

But if I request from **cURL**, the second param `build_num` was missing, it seems rails lost this param.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3456/api/pipeline?job_id=16&build_num=23
```

And the rails backend logs looks like this:

```
Started GET "/api/pipeline?job_id=16" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-15 23:12:30 +0800
Processing by Api::PipelineController#index as JSON
Parameters: {"job_id"=>"16"}
```

I searched google but without fortune. Anyone could provide me some tips would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your shell recognizes `&` as an instruction to run the command in the background. For example, take a look at these two outputs:

```
$ (sleep 3 && echo Awake); echo Finished
Awake
Finished
$ (sleep 3 && echo Awake) & echo Finished
[1] 23699
Finished
Awake
```

The second command runs `sleep 3 && echo Awake` in the background, allowing `Finished` to print before `sleep` is done. `23699` is the process ID that's been backgrounded, in case you need to send it signals.

So when you run

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3456/api/pipeline?job_id=16&build_num=23
```

you're actually running

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:3456/api/pipeline?job_id=16 &
build_num=23
```

In a lot of cases, the shell would report a `command not found` error, but you also happen to have stumbled upon variable setting, and if now you `echo $build_num`, your shell will print `23`.

The upshot is that any time you use cURL with an URL that's got parameters in it, wrap the URL in quotes. Single quotes are safest because the shell won't do any variable evaluation, etc. inside them (eg. `echo "number is $build_num"` prints `number is 23`, while `echo 'number is $build_num'` prints `number is $build_num`), but double quotes will be fine as long as there's nothing in the URL the shell recognizes as special (`$`, `` ` ``, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the request URL in double quotes:

```
curl "http://127.0.0.1:3456/api/pipeline?job_id=16&build_num=23"
```

Because shell is interfering with & character. From the [curl docs](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#URL):

> When using [] or {} sequences when invoked from a command line prompt, you probably have to put the full URL within double quotes to avoid the shell from interfering with it. This also goes for other characters treated special, like for example '&', '?' and '*'.